# How do I use the query parameters in the Dark Sky Forecast API ?(forecast.io)

Tags: api, weather, weather-api

I'm using the Dark Sky Forecast API to retrieve some weather information.

When I read the [official doc](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2#options), I found that the "option" section describes the usage of query parameters.

For example,

> The API request may optionally be modified through the use of query parameters. It will respond to the following:
>
> callback=[callback]: Return the API response as JSONP. Please use
>   caution when using this, since exposing your API key to the public is
>   a security hazard and, if abused, will result in the revokation of
>   your API key. However, if developing a personal- or internal-use app,
>   this is a convenient method of doing so.
>
> units=[setting]: Return the
>   API response in units other than the default Imperial units. In
>   particular, the following settings are possible:
>
> - us: The default, as outlined above.
> - si: Returns results in SI units. In particular, properties now have the following units:
> - ...

I know how to get the weather information by take advantages of the call

```
 https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
```

But I don't know how to combine the query parameters with it.

Any ideas?

---

**2015/10/23 UPDATE**

Thank to Logan Kearns, using ? parameter solved my question. Make sure the query parameters are in lowercase.

```
https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE?lang=zh-tw&units=si
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how you change the units. I assume that other query parameters would be set in a similar manner, using the '?' to separate them.

> https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE?UNITS=us

Answer (score 2):

Just an update, since url changed and with few other parameters:

You can add units to mention the type of unit conversion required
You can add exclude for excluding certain data in the response like hourly updates.

```
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/LAT,LONG?units=si&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,alerts
```